# Array and distance between points - php

Tags: php, dictionary, geolocation

I'm going to develop a location based app and i need some help! I have an array (in php) which store some (~3800) coordinates.This array looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [lat] => 38.900516 [lgn] => -77.076881 ) 
[1] => Array ( [lat] => 38.900491 [lgn] => -77.0768505 ) 
[2] => Array ( [lat] => 38.900466 [lgn] => -77.07682 ) 
[3] => Array ( [lat] => 38.9004775 [lgn] => -77.07677425 ) 
[4] => Array ( [lat] => 38.900489 [lgn] => -77.0767285 )....)
```

Now i want to create new array (for example $new_arr[]) which contains values from every    20 values from the first array($old_array).

for example: the $new_arr contains $old_array[0],$old_array[20],$old_array[40]....

The problem is that the first array contains random coordinates and maybe $old_array[20] and $old_array[40] are near coordinates....I want import to the new array values where the distance between them is more than 20 metres! Any idea?

ps.Sorry for my english!

Comment: So, unless the difference between `$old_array[0]` and `$old_array[20]` are at least 20 meters, `$old_array[20]` won't be appended onto `$new_arr`?

Comment: Yes but i want ANY value in new array has at least 20 metres distance from each other

Comment: Wouldn't every value be added then? Suppose you have 3 points, ( |--|----------|), because the third point is far, both points would be added.

Comment: added the first and the third point...BUT in the old array the values are random

Comment: There are 7,218,100 combinations of 2 coordinates in 3800 coordinates.You will need to eliminate all the distances less than 20 meters before creating new arrays

Comment: if i import all values of array in mysql how i can sort(index) them from distance?